# How to bind to get-only property of API class instace?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, data-binding

May be my formulating of this question is incorrect ("How to bind to get-only property of API class instace?") but here's my problem:
I'm creating powerpoint vsto add-in and I need to bind the SlideIndex property of concrete slide to textbox on the windows form. SlideIndex property has only get accessor. I found that in case of binding I need to use mvvm. According to examples on mvvm theme I installed MvvmLightLibs to my solution from NuGet Packege Manager and desided to "wrap" slide object with this way:

```
public class SlideWraper: ViewModelBase
{
   private PowerPoint.Slide Sld;
   public int SlideIndex
   {
      get
      {
         return Sld.SlideIndex;
      }
      set
      {
         RaisePropertyChanged(() => Sld.SlideIndex);
      }  
   }

   public SlideWraper(PowerPoint.Slide sld)
   {
      Sld=sld;
   }
}
```

Here's my code of binding creation:

```
...
PowerPoint.Slide ConcreteSlide=this.Application.ActivePresentation.
  Slides.FindBySlideID(257);
SlideWraper MyWraper=new SlideWraper(ConcreteSlide);
MyTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", MyWraper, "SlideIndex"));
...
```

But this realization fills textbox with correct slide index only at the start of the program. When I replace slide (slide index changed) MyTextBox.Text is not changed.

How can I bind to get-only property of slide?

Answer (score 0):

A few options here. If `PowerPoint.Slide` supports INPC then you should expose it directly...

```
private PowerPoint.Slide Sld;
public PowerPoint.Slide Slide
{
   get {return Sld;}
   set {this.Sld = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Slide);}  
}
```

... and then in XAML bind to `Slide.SlideIndex`.

If PowerPoint.Slide doesn't support INPC then you'll need to create a regular int property in your view model and arrange for PowerPoint.Slide to update that property in response to its `SlideIndex` value changing.

Finally if you know that SlideIndex has just updated then you can just call `RaisePropertyChanged("Slide")', this can be slow because it will cause all bindings to the Slide properties to update, but sometimes it's the only choice.

Either way, automatic updates can't just magically work by themselves, PowerPoint.Slide needs to have some mechanism to notify the rest of the program that its `SlideIndex` property has changed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately INPC is not supperted - I tried your code.
"...arrange for PowerPoint.Slide to update that property in response to its SlideIndex value changing" - the problem is that I can't programmatically catch the moment when SlideIndex is changed. I mean that I can change the order of skides in presenttion using UI but there's no event in vsto powerpoint that is responsible for this order changing.

Comment: You'll have to provide more specific details about the PowerPoint.Slide class then. Do you have control of the source or does it come from a library? Any problem with automatically creating a proxy object that provides INPC? Data-binding doesn't provide any special capability that isn't already supported by the language, at the end of the day you'd face the exact same problem if you were developing this for, say, WinForms. How would you normally keep your GUI elements synchronized with your PowerPoint.Slide class?

Comment: I don't have controll of PowerPoint.Slide, it's in the library.

Comment: I suppose that WinForms isn't a best idea in this case too. And I used it just for example. My purpose is to raise event after changing SlideIndex property that has only get accessor. So TextBox from WinForms was binded to SlideIndex and it had to raise its TextChanged event when SlideIndex was changed.
I didn't try WPF for this situation yet and I think it will work. But is there any another way (without using WPF) to catch SlideIndex changing.
P.S. I don't want to use WPF because I don't want solve this problem just by GUI.

Comment: If you mean that MyWraper is a proxy object: it's created successfully without any problems but TextBox doesn't react on SlideIndex changing.